# How can I make an SLTextField tappable?

Tags: objective-c, testing, uitextfield, automated-tests, subliminal

I have been writing a test with "Subliminal's" "SLTextField" and have run into some really annoying issues lately.

I have written a test which should update a text field, clear it, and update it again.

For some reason when I use "SLTextField" to change the element text I consistently receive errors stating that "SLTextFields" aren't tappable elements.  Is this true?  If so, what is the point of having an "SLTextField" class at all?

I can rewrite the same test code to find the element as an "SLElement", at which point I can tap the element, open up a keyboard object and type the necessary text, but it seems like I'm circumventing the entire functionality of Subliminal in doing this.

What's wrong w/"SLTextField"?

**Code:**

```
SLTextField *textField = [SLTextField elementWithAccessibilityLabel:fieldName];
SLWaitUntilTrue([textField isTappable], DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
textField.text = newValue;
```

The above code throws an error, stating that "textField" never becomes tappable.  Alternatively, the code below works perfectly, though it's unnecessarily verbose and seems to make "SLTextField" superfluous.

**Code:**

```
SLElement *field = [SLElement elementWithAccessibilityLabel:fieldName];
[field tapAtActivationPoint];
//fill with text
SLKeyboard *kb = [SLKeyboard keyboard];
SLKeyboardKey *deleteKey = [SLKeyboardKey elementWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Delete"];
while(![field.value isEqualToString:@""]){
    [deleteKey touchAndHoldWithDuration:1.2];
}
[kb typeString:newValue];
SLKeyboardKey *doneKey = [SLKeyboardKey elementWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Next"];
if(![doneKey isValid]){
    doneKey = [SLKeyboardKey elementWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Done"];
}
[doneKey tap];
[kb hide];
```

Comment: Hi @Maixy, I'm Subliminal's maintainer. When you try to use `SLTextField`, is the error you get specifically that the field isn't tappable, or perhaps that it "does not exist"?

Comment: Hi Jeff,  Unfortunately the error I'm getting is that the text field is not tappable.  If I retrieve the same element as an SLElement, though, during the same debug, it IS tappable.

Answer (score 3):

Is your TextField within a TableViewCell? And are you seeing this on iOS 7?

If so, it might have been fixed by https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/pull/202 (merged 6/6/2014).

Comment: @people in the LQP queue; there's not much good in copy and pasting the linked patch into the question. This answer is fine as it is.

Comment: @Maixy https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/pull/202 would have explained your problem like this: a table view cell with a text field shares the label of that field. When you tried to set the text of the _text field_, Subliminal found the field but couldn't tap on it. But when you let Subliminal find "an element" with the field's name, it found and tapped on the _cell_. It didn't matter that that element wasn't a text field because that tap focused the text field and then you used the keyboard directly.